# wants to provide password to tightvnc server by using script

Tags: ruby, vnc-server

I am installating tightvnc server on my ubuntu machine by using ruby script my script contain following:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby env    
`sudo apt-get --force-yes -y install tightvncserver`
`printf "%s\n%s\n" "demo123" "demo123" | vncserver :1`
```

I used printf way because vncserver ask for password on terminal, But that way failed, Is their any better way to solve this?

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532640/2073804

Answer (score -1):

You'd want to use `vncpassword` to [create a password file](http://www.dotkam.com/2009/03/22/vnc-into-remote-server-without-typing-a-password/):

> Step 2. Create a vnc password file with “vncpassword”.
>
> ```
> $ vncpasswd
> Using password file /home/user/.vnc/passwd
> VNC directory /home/user/.vnc does not exist, creating.
> Password: [TYPE YOUR VNC PASSWORD HERE]
> Verify: [TYPE YOUR VNC PASSWORD HERE]
> Would you like to enter a view-only password (y/n)? n
> ```

and then use that file in your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby env    
`sudo apt-get --force-yes -y install tightvncserver`
`vncserver -p /home/user/.vnc/passwd`
```

Comment: This is interactive way to provide password using terminal , I already know this way, I wants to provide password using ruby script so that terminal not prompt and ask user to provide password.Hope this clear...