# Set up TightVNC programmatically with BASH

Tags: bash, debian, expect, vnc-server, tightvnc

I'm writing a script to set up VNC (amongst other things) on many debian based devices. I want to include VNC in this setup (specifically, tightVNC if possible) and have it set a given password (randomly generated by the script). The problem is, every guide I find seems to assume that a human is doing this, and is ready to sit and type in the password and press enter. I can't seem to get Bash to echo a password to VNC (it always says 'password too short') nor can I get 'expect' to work properly.

An example guide I found looks like this: 
http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc

I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Going to configure VNC"
#turn on vnc server
tightvncserver
#spit out password to vnc server for first run only
echo $password
#confirm the pw
echo $password
```

But, on every virginal run of tightvncserver it always asks for a password to be inputted by hand:

```
Going to configure VNC

You will require a password to access your desktops.

Password: Password too short
```

How can I #1 get around this, or #2 use bash / expect to GIVE it a password to make it happy?

Comment: The `echo`s don't write content to the `tightvncserver` process, so this doesn't work the way you want it to regardless.

Comment: ...because, as this is currently written, the `echo`s won't be run at all until after `tightvncserver` exits.

Comment: Also, `tightvncserver` is reading for passwords from the TTY, not from stdin, so you can't pipe to it at all.

Comment: Anyhow, the right way to do this is to use the `vncpasswd` command directly, rather than relying on `tightvncserver` to prompt and then trying to pretend to be a TTY to answer that prompt.

Comment: Sometimes password is ignored, so set also the correct file permission: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532640/2073804

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# Configure VNC password
umask 0077                                        # use safe default permissions
mkdir -p "$HOME/.vnc"                             # create config directory
chmod go-rwx "$HOME/.vnc"                         # enforce safe permissions
vncpasswd -f <<<"$password" >"$HOME/.vnc/passwd"  # generate and write a password
```

Modify to taste, if your packaging for tightvnc uses a location other than `~/.vnc/` for the `passwd` file.

---

If you have separate view-only and full-control passwords, then:

```
vncpasswd -f <<<"$full_password"$'\n'"$view_password" >"$HOME/.vnc/passwd"
```

If you needed compatibility with `/bin/sh` (or otherwise weren't using `#!/bin/bash` shebangs), this would instead be:

```
vncpasswd -f >"$HOME/.vnc/passwd" <<EOF
$full_password
$view_password
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't seem to find the tightvncserver password location (I followed your steps, it all worked, but it still asked for a password.... grrr!) But, I may be able to search for that on my own. I've looked in home/.vnc/passwd and while there WAS a file there, I guess I may have put it there on my own?

Comment: Dunno. The `tightvnc` package I use installs as `vncserver`, not `tightvncserver`, so our distros do things very differently.

Comment: ...that said, you might run `tightvncserver` by hand, set a password, and then use something like `find "$HOME" -mmin -30` to find places changed in the last 30 minutes as a way to look for where it was stored. That, or read the `tightvncserver` script (on my platform it's perl, but quite readable perl) and see what storage location it's using that way.

Comment: You can issue `strace tightvncserver 2>&1|grep passw` to find it. Then you'll see e.g. `stat64("/root/.vnc/passwd", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=16, ...}) = 0` as last line. Don't forget to do `chmod 600 /root/.vnc/passwd` else it will be silently ignored.

Comment: I got `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: @realtebo, `<<<` is bash syntax, and so is `$'\n'`. These constructs don't work with `/bin/sh`, so they can't be used in scripts with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang. Either use a bash shebang instead (as the OP does -- you'll note that this is an answer to a question tagged `bash`, not `sh`) or switch to using heredoc instead of herestring syntax.