# How to set Vncserver in bash script (redhat6)

Tags: bash, passwords, redhat, vnc, vnc-server

I am using a script to automatically set up a computer. I need to assign a password to the vnc server for the user, which is normally done using the vncserver command. However, it prompts for the user to enter and re-enter their password, neither of which the script is capable of doing.

So, how can I set up the VNC password without an interactive prompt?

Comment: Like this when password is silently ignored: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532640/2073804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following bash script sample:

```
#!/bin/sh

vncpasswd << EOF
123456
123456
EOF
```