# trying to redirect & vncpasswd as a different user (bash)

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, vnc

I have a unique need to execute "vncpasswd" as a different user in a script.
It also needs to be non-interactive and automatic.

I'm using redirect and also as a different user.
Using info from (trying to combine)

Thank you.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91534/how-to-pipe-to-bash-as-a-different-user 
and
[How to set Vncserver in bash script (redhat6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851343/how-to-set-vncserver-in-bash-script-redhat6)

Tried variations of

```
#!/bin/sh

'vncpasswd << EOF
tvnc1234
tvnc1234
EOF' | sudo -u vnc bash
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo -u vnc bash 'vncpasswd' << EOF
tvnc1234
tvnc1234
EOF
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/328240/assign-vnc-password-using-script ?

Comment: still same issue where I need to do that as a different user. The post you mentioned assumes I'm not changing with "sudo -u username"

Comment: The sudo should not really matter: What happens if you just use the scripts from the link as the root user (so you don't have to sudo in that test)?

Comment: due to ".vnc" staying in "/home/user/.vnc" vs "/root/.vnc/", it breaks the script format. I have to run it on a non-root with elevated privilege with nopasswd.

Comment: sudo means run as other user, so that is no surprise. Alternative: You can maybe add your user to the group allowed to run vnc direct so that the sudo is not required anymore

Comment: it's not the issue of sudo rights, but invoking "vncpasswd" command as a different user and creating appropriate files in that particular user's profile. The redirect command works without "sudo -u" though. (Worst case, might just tell people to create user manually and run the script inside the user). Thanks.