# Can I set password for tightVNC through powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, puppet, tightvnc

I would like maintain tightVNC through puppet, I was able to install using chocolatey provider.

How I can maintain the configuration (password set) of tightVNC through puppet?

Are there any tightVNC commands available to set the password, so that I can run the commands using puppet (exec resource)

Thanks.

Comment: TightVNC on Windows stores its configuration in the registry. Use the [registry provider](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/registry) for writing the (encrypted) password to the respective registry value.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. How I can encrypt the password and assign to the key while declaring in puppet?

Comment: From what I heard TightVNC uses a hard-coded encryption key, so you could probably install TightVNC somewhere, set the password manually, read the value from the registry and put that into your config.

Comment: If you are using master-agent setup you can use something like [https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml](hiera-eyaml) to store encrypted password in manifests that will be decrypted when compiling manifest on puppet server.

Comment: Yes you can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532640/2073804

Answer (score 2):

You can set tightvnc password in windows regedit directly.

Reg path : `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TightVNC\Server`

But, Tight vnc storing password in encrypted form.

So you have to encrypt password first.

For encryption then password there are ready available vncpasswd utility are there

For Vncpasswd utility : https://github.com/trinitronx/vncpasswd.py

Answer (score 1):

Configure TightVNC server using the GUI and set the password you want. Then run from an elevated command prompt:

```
reg export HKLM\Software\TightVNC\Server foo.reg
```

The generated file `foo.reg` contains your password in vnc-encrypted format and your other preferences for the TightVNC server. Review the file using Notepad if desired.

To install your password and preferences on another machine, copy `foo.reg` and merge it into the registry from an elevated command prompt:

```
reg import foo.reg
```

Restart the TightVNC service if needed:

```
sc stop tvnserver
sc start tvnserver
```

Answer (score 0):

The only devops way i found is use `choco` to install:

```
choco install -y tightvnc \
--installArguments "\
  SET_USEVNCAUTHENTICATION=1 \
  VALUE_OF_USEVNCAUTHENTICATION=1 \
  SET_PASSWORD=1 \
  VALUE_OF_PASSWORD=${vnc_password}"
```